# Hibernate Foriegn key not working, SSH

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, hibernate-mapping

3 tables in mysql like this:

```
CREATE TABLE tstudent(
  id varchar(36) primary key not null,
  firstname VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
  lastname VARCHAR(30)  NOT NULL,
  grade int   NOT NULL,
  sex VARCHAR(1)      NOT NULL,
  birthday DATE,
  dayorboarding VARCHAR(1)    NOT NULL,
  age int   ,
  house VARCHAR(20),
  mentor VARCHAR(50)
);


CREATE TABLE ttrip(
  id varchar(36) primary key not null,
  departureday       DATE         NOT NULL,
  name varchar(100) not null unique
);

CREATE TABLE tsignup(
  id varchar(36) primary key not null,
  s_id varchar(36) not null,
  FOREIGN KEY (s_id) REFERENCES tstudent(id), 
  t_id varchar(36) not null,
  FOREIGN KEY (t_id) REFERENCES ttrip(id),
  departuretransport   VARCHAR(1)   NOT NULL,
  returntransport    VARCHAR(1)   NOT NULL,
  remark TEXT
);
```

tstudent model likes this:

```
package cz.model;

import java.util.Date;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Set;
import javax.persistence.CascadeType;
import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.FetchType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.OneToMany;
import javax.persistence.Table;
import javax.persistence.Temporal;
import javax.persistence.TemporalType;

/**
 * Tstudent entity. @author MyEclipse Persistence Tools
 */
@Entity
@Table(name = "tstudent", catalog = "rlcbau")
public class Tstudent implements java.io.Serializable {

    // Fields

    private String id;
    private String firstname;
    private String lastname;
    private Integer grade;
    private String sex;
    private Date birthday;
    private String dayorboarding;
    private Integer age;
    private String house;
    private String mentor;
    private Set<Tsignup> tsignups = new HashSet<Tsignup>(0);

    // Constructors

    /** default constructor */
    public Tstudent() {
    }

    /** minimal constructor */
    public Tstudent(String id, String firstname, String lastname, Integer grade, String sex, String dayorboarding) {
        this.id = id;
        this.firstname = firstname;
        this.lastname = lastname;
        this.grade = grade;
        this.sex = sex;
        this.dayorboarding = dayorboarding;
    }

    /** full constructor */
    public Tstudent(String id, String firstname, String lastname, Integer grade, String sex, Date birthday, String dayorboarding, Integer age, String house, String mentor, Set<Tsignup> tsignups) {
        this.id = id;
        this.firstname = firstname;
        this.lastname = lastname;
        this.grade = grade;
        this.sex = sex;
        this.birthday = birthday;
        this.dayorboarding = dayorboarding;
        this.age = age;
        this.house = house;
        this.mentor = mentor;
        this.tsignups = tsignups;
    }

    // Property accessors
    @Id
    @Column(name = "id", unique = true, nullable = false, length = 36)
    public String getId() {
        return this.id;
    }

    public void setId(String id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    @Column(name = "firstname", nullable = false, length = 30)
    public String getFirstname() {
        return this.firstname;
    }

    public void setFirstname(String firstname) {
        this.firstname = firstname;
    }

    @Column(name = "lastname", nullable = false, length = 30)
    public String getLastname() {
        return this.lastname;
    }

    public void setLastname(String lastname) {
        this.lastname = lastname;
    }

    @Column(name = "grade", nullable = false)
    public Integer getGrade() {
        return this.grade;
    }

    public void setGrade(Integer grade) {
        this.grade = grade;
    }

    @Column(name = "sex", nullable = false, length = 1)
    public String getSex() {
        return this.sex;
    }

    public void setSex(String sex) {
        this.sex = sex;
    }

    @Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
    @Column(name = "birthday", length = 10)
    public Date getBirthday() {
        return this.birthday;
    }

    public void setBirthday(Date birthday) {
        this.birthday = birthday;
    }

    @Column(name = "dayorboarding", nullable = false, length = 1)
    public String getDayorboarding() {
        return this.dayorboarding;
    }

    public void setDayorboarding(String dayorboarding) {
        this.dayorboarding = dayorboarding;
    }

    @Column(name = "age")
    public Integer getAge() {
        return this.age;
    }

    public void setAge(Integer age) {
        this.age = age;
    }

    @Column(name = "house", length = 20)
    public String getHouse() {
        return this.house;
    }

    public void setHouse(String house) {
        this.house = house;
    }

    @Column(name = "mentor", length = 50)
    public String getMentor() {
        return this.mentor;
    }

    public void setMentor(String mentor) {
        this.mentor = mentor;
    }

    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "tstudent")
    public Set<Tsignup> getTsignups() {
        return this.tsignups;
    }

    public void setTsignups(Set<Tsignup> tsignups) {
        this.tsignups = tsignups;
    }

}
```

ttrip model likes this:

```
package cz.model;

import java.util.Date;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Set;
import javax.persistence.CascadeType;
import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.FetchType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.OneToMany;
import javax.persistence.Table;
import javax.persistence.Temporal;
import javax.persistence.TemporalType;
import javax.persistence.UniqueConstraint;

/**
 * Ttrip entity. @author MyEclipse Persistence Tools
 */
@Entity
@Table(name = "ttrip", catalog = "rlcbau", uniqueConstraints = @UniqueConstraint(columnNames = "name"))
public class Ttrip implements java.io.Serializable {

    // Fields

    private String id;
    private String departureday;
    private String name;
    private Set<Tsignup> tsignups = new HashSet<Tsignup>(0);

    // Constructors

    /** default constructor */
    public Ttrip() {
    }

    /** minimal constructor */
    public Ttrip(String id, String departureday, String name) {
        this.id = id;
        this.departureday = departureday;
        this.name = name;
    }

    /** full constructor */
    public Ttrip(String id, String departureday, String name, Set<Tsignup> tsignups) {
        this.id = id;
        this.departureday = departureday;
        this.name = name;
        this.tsignups = tsignups;
    }

    // Property accessors
    @Id
    @Column(name = "id", unique = true, nullable = false, length = 36)
    public String getId() {
        return this.id;
    }

    public void setId(String id) {
        this.id = id;
    }


    @Column(name = "departureday", nullable = false, length = 10)
    public String getDepartureday() {
        return this.departureday;
    }

    public void setDepartureday(String departureday) {
        this.departureday = departureday;
    }

    @Column(name = "name", unique = true, nullable = false, length = 100)
    public String getName() {
        return this.name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "ttrip")
    public Set<Tsignup> getTsignups() {
        return this.tsignups;
    }

    public void setTsignups(Set<Tsignup> tsignups) {
        this.tsignups = tsignups;
    }

}
```

tsignup model likes this:

```
import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.FetchType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.JoinColumn;
import javax.persistence.ManyToOne;
import javax.persistence.Table;

/**
 * Tsignup entity. @author MyEclipse Persistence Tools
 */
@Entity
@Table(name = "tsignup", catalog = "rlcbau")
public class Tsignup implements java.io.Serializable {

    // Fields

    private String id;
    private Ttrip ttrip;
    private Tstudent tstudent;
    private String departuretransport;
    private String returntransport;
    private String remark;

    // Constructors

    /** default constructor */
    public Tsignup() {
    }

    /** minimal constructor */
    public Tsignup(String id, Ttrip ttrip, Tstudent tstudent, String departuretransport, String returntransport) {
        this.id = id;
        this.ttrip = ttrip;
        this.tstudent = tstudent;
        this.departuretransport = departuretransport;
        this.returntransport = returntransport;
    }

    /** full constructor */
    public Tsignup(String id, Ttrip ttrip, Tstudent tstudent, String departuretransport, String returntransport, String remark) {
        this.id = id;
        this.ttrip = ttrip;
        this.tstudent = tstudent;
        this.departuretransport = departuretransport;
        this.returntransport = returntransport;
        this.remark = remark;
    }

    // Property accessors
    @Id
    @Column(name = "id", unique = true, nullable = false, length = 36)
    public String getId() {
        return this.id;
    }

    public void setId(String id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "t_id", nullable = false)
    public Ttrip getTtrip() {
        return this.ttrip;
    }

    public void setTtrip(Ttrip ttrip) {
        this.ttrip = ttrip;
    }

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "s_id", nullable = false)
    public Tstudent getTstudent() {
        return this.tstudent;
    }

    public void setTstudent(Tstudent tstudent) {
        this.tstudent = tstudent;
    }

    @Column(name = "departuretransport", nullable = false, length = 1)
    public String getDeparturetransport() {
        return this.departuretransport;
    }

    public void setDeparturetransport(String departuretransport) {
        this.departuretransport = departuretransport;
    }

    @Column(name = "returntransport", nullable = false, length = 1)
    public String getReturntransport() {
        return this.returntransport;
    }

    public void setReturntransport(String returntransport) {
        this.returntransport = returntransport;
    }

    @Column(name = "remark", length = 65535)
    public String getRemark() {
        return this.remark;
    }

    public void setRemark(String remark) {
        this.remark = remark;
    }

}
```

I have "signupAction" likes this:

```
    public void save_stulst(){
        Json j = new Json();
        try {
//          logger.info(signup.getId()+signup.getS_id()+signup.getT_id()+signup.getRemark()+signup.getDeparturetransport()+signup.getReturntransport());
            signupService.save_stulst(signup);
            j.setSuccess(true);
            j.setMsg("Signup succeeds!");

        } catch (Exception e) {
            j.setMsg(e.getMessage());
        }
        super.writeJson(j);
    }
```

and in the service level, I have "signupService":

```
@Service(value="signupService")
public class SignupServiceImpl implements SignupServiceI {

    /**
     * Logger for this class
     */
    private static final Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(StudentServiceImpl.class);


    private BaseDaoI<Tsignup> signupDao;
    private BaseDaoI<Tstudent> studentDao;
    private BaseDaoI<Ttrip> tripDao;


    public BaseDaoI<Tsignup> getSignupDao() {
        return signupDao;
    }

    @Autowired
    public void setSignupDao(BaseDaoI<Tsignup> signupDao) {
        this.signupDao = signupDao;
    }

    public BaseDaoI<Ttrip> getTripDao() {
        return tripDao;
    }

    @Autowired
    public void setTripDao(BaseDaoI<Ttrip> tripDao) {
        this.tripDao = tripDao;
    }

    public BaseDaoI<Tstudent> getStudentDao() {
        return studentDao;
    }

    @Autowired
    public void setStudentDao(BaseDaoI<Tstudent> studentDao) {
        this.studentDao = studentDao;
    }

    @Override
    public void save_stulst(Signup signup) {

        Tsignup tsignup = new Tsignup();
        Tstudent tstudent = studentDao.get(Tstudent.class, signup.getS_id());
        Ttrip ttrip = tripDao.get(Ttrip.class, signup.getT_id());


        BeanUtils.copyProperties(signup, tsignup, new String[]{"id"});
        tsignup.setId(UUID.randomUUID().toString());
        tsignup.setTstudent(tstudent);
        tsignup.setTtrip(ttrip);


        signupDao.save(tsignup);
    }
```

It is the baseDaoImpl:
    package cz.dao.impl;

```
import org.apache.log4j.Logger;

import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;

import org.hibernate.Query;
import org.hibernate.Session;
import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

import cz.dao.BaseDaoI;

@Repository("baseDao")
public class BaseDaoImpl<T> implements BaseDaoI<T> {
/**
 * Logger for this class
 */
private static final Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(BaseDaoImpl.class);

private SessionFactory sessionFactory;

public SessionFactory getSessionFactory() {
    return sessionFactory;
}

@Autowired
public void setSessionFactory(SessionFactory sessionFactory) {
    this.sessionFactory = sessionFactory;
}

private Session getCurrentSession(){
    return this.sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
}

@Override
public Serializable save(T o) {
    return this.getCurrentSession().save(o);
}

@Override
public T get(Class<T> c, Serializable id ) {
    return (T) this.getCurrentSession().get(c, id);
}

@Override
public T get(String hql) {
    Query q = this.getCurrentSession().createQuery(hql);
    List<T> l = q.list();
    if (l!=null && l.size()>0){
        return l.get(0);
    }else{
        return null;
    }
}

@Override
public T get(String hql, Map<String, Object> params) {
    Query q = this.getCurrentSession().createQuery(hql);
    if(params != null && !params.isEmpty()){
        for (String key : params.keySet()){
            q.setParameter(key, params.get(key));
        }
    }
    List<T> l = q.list();
    if (l!=null && l.size()>0){
        return l.get(0);
    }else{
        return null;
    }
}

@Override
public void delete(T o) {
    this.getCurrentSession().delete(o); 
}

@Override
public void update(T o) {
    this.getCurrentSession().update(o);
}

@Override
public void saveOrUpdate(T o) {
    this.getCurrentSession().save(o);

}

@Override
public List<T> find(String hql) {
    Query q = this.getCurrentSession().createQuery(hql);
    return q.list();
}

@Override
public List<T> find(String hql, Map<String, Object> params) {
    Query q = this.getCurrentSession().createQuery(hql);
    if(params != null && !params.isEmpty()){
        for (String key : params.keySet()){
            q.setParameter(key, params.get(key));
        }
    }
    return q.list();

}

@Override
public List<T> find(String hql, Map<String, Object> params, int page, int rows) {
    Query q = this.getCurrentSession().createQuery(hql);
    if(params != null && !params.isEmpty()){
        for (String key : params.keySet()){
            q.setParameter(key, params.get(key));
        }
    }
    return q.setFirstResult((page - 1) * rows).setMaxResults(rows).list();
}

@Override
public List<T> find(String hql, int page, int rows) {
    Query q = this.getCurrentSession().createQuery(hql);
    return q.setFirstResult((page - 1) * rows).setMaxResults(rows).list();
}

@Override
public Long count(String hql) {
    Query q = this.getCurrentSession().createQuery(hql);
    return (Long) q.uniqueResult();
}

@Override
public Long count(String hql, Map<String, Object> params) {
    Query q = this.getCurrentSession().createQuery(hql);
    if(params != null && !params.isEmpty()){
        for (String key : params.keySet()){
            q.setParameter(key, params.get(key));
        }
    }
    return (Long) q.uniqueResult();
}

@Override
public int executeHql(String hql) {
    Query q = this.getCurrentSession().createQuery(hql);
    return q.executeUpdate();
}





}
```

Question: When I try to save from web, I get errors like this:

```
[org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper]SQL Error: 1048, SQLState: 23000
[org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper]Column 's_id' cannot be null
[org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.batch.internal.AbstractBatchImpl]HHH000010: On release of batch it still contained JDBC statements
```

I am new to hibernate, not sure which step is wrong. I've given ttrip and tstudent into tsignup model.. It should have been saved

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well your definition of "tsignup" table clearly shows a NOT NULL constraint on "s_id" column. Do you really need this? 
If not remove it and this should work

Cheers 
Anant

Comment: Yes I need this as not null

Comment: your "save_stulst" API should have a "signup" object populated with appropriate "student" object then!

Comment: Sorry everyone, My bad. I messed up the values. :(

Comment: If my answer helped I wonder if you could vote for the same. Will help to improve my profile Cheers

Answer (score 0):

Change your  `tsignup` table

```
  CREATE TABLE tsignup(
  ...
  s_id varchar(36) not null,
  ...
```

To

```
  CREATE TABLE tsignup(
  ...
  s_id VARCHAR(36) NULL,
  ...
```

Comment: I need this as not null. changed table as you suggested, but it gives me: NULL value in s_id

Comment: If you really need that column as not null then you have to pass a value to that as well.

Comment: Sorry everyone, My bad. I messed up the values. :(